# Can a Google Chrome extension/web-application request its own ID string?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need to specify the ID of a Google Chrome web-application for checking URLs (eg: chrome-extension://[id_goes_here]/application.html). Is there some way I can call the ID with JavaScript and then construct the URL?

I'm thinking of using something along the lines of:

```
"chrome-extension://" + whatever_calls_the_ID + "/application.html";
```

to check the URLs, but need to know how to call the ID.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In javascript:

```
var myid = chrome.i18n.getMessage("@@extension_id");
```

(no extra permissions required to make this call)

[More info...](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/i18n.html#overview-predefined)